# How to build Android without sources?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I have an old, obsolete Android e-reader - [Highscreen Alex(Another name Spring design Alex)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_eReader). It's running Android 1.6, has 2.6.28 linux kernel. But vendor doesnt ever support this device, and not provided source codes, and the stock firmware don't support many things, such as play market, file manager, etc.

So i want to upgrade the firmware, and kernel maybe. There are no sources, so i can't just run `make -j4`. But device have pre-installed bootloader, so i can install system, data, cache partitions, and can pull it from device using `dd if=/dev/block/mtdblkXY of=/sdcard/XY.img`. That images can be open in programs like Winimage or by mounting it in linux.

How to edit this files(what i have to add (for example, new /frameworks from another device or emulator)
or what i can do in this situation for make Android upgrade? Does i need new kernel, or i can only upgrade the Android frameworks and etc. for it?

Comment: if something unclear, please ask

Answer (score -1):

Your idea "to edit files inside system image" is not realistic.

You have to purchase a new modern reader - e.g. Onyx T68 is powered by Android-4, see http://www.onyx-international.com.cn/index.php/en/boox-products/boox-t-series for details.

Or you can purchase another device which runs CyanogenMod to play with it, consult http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices to choose the particular device.